# .Net Parsing Fixed Width Data... From a Concatenated, Single, Fixed-Width Column

Tags: sql, .net, etl

I was bored and looking at old code that runs like molasses on a cold day.  I found that a group of tables in our accounting system - each with 500,000 records of ~20 datapoints - that use a single column of concatenated, fixed-width values instead of separate columns.  (Fixing the tables isn't an option.)  An old .net ETL project is grabbing all records, doing a bunch of substrings on each record to set an object's corresponding attributes, then sending the object to merge with production data via a stored proc.

The way it is working is fine.  It works.  And, to be perfectly honest, I doubt I'll be given the go-ahead to fix it even if I come up with a better solution, but **I was curious to see if anyone knew of a better way of doing this**, because it's not entirely unlikely that I'll face a situation like this in the future.

I was thinking that if there was a way to use the TextFieldParser to parse a static string instead of a file/stream that might be a valid idea.  Or, instead, I could write the entire table to a text file and then use the TextFieldParser to send data to the SProc.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser does show that TextFieldParser is quite a bit faster than split, which I would assume is tantamount to the string manipulation our project is currently doing with substring.  So there may be something to that idea.

Or perhaps the whole, old project should be dumped for a shiny new SSIS project.  Would it also have to write the records to a flat file before importing into SQL?  Or can it import directly from the table?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is your knowledge of NoSQL?

Comment: Nonexistent.  But I love to learn.  You think this would be a case where it would be beneficial?

Comment: a concatenated fixed width column seems like non-structured data to me...structured query language (sql) vs no structure query lang.   I'm not the best with nosql myself, but it seems like this is an optimal use case.  For SQL to function at it's best for you, you will want to normalize this column (which it appears your current ETL process is doing)